# What does the "i" in Apple product names mean?

Tags: apple-inc

iPhone, iPod, iPad, iCal, iLife, etc. Does the "i" mean anything? And is it a trademark for Apple?

Comment: Surprised nobody asked this before.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When Steve Jobs first introduced the iMac in 1998, he proclaimed that the *i* stood for *Internet*. Jobs went on to say, "*i* also means some other things to us" and displayed a presentation slide with the keywords:

> internet
>   individual
>   instruct
>   inform
>   inspire

You can even view [video of this event](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0BHPtoTctDY).

The "i" was first used on the iBook and iMac. These were produced as Steve Jobs wanted a pro and consumer model of a desktop and portable computer. This later rolled out with more products, iSight, iPod, iPhone, iPad.

Yes the products are trademarked, but using an "i" itself before a product is not trademarked and it cannot be. Here is [Apple's trademark list](http://www.apple.com/legal/trademark/appletmlist.html)

Comment: Thats the correct Answer..

Comment: This is also what's been stated in the biography by Walter Isaacson.

Answer (score 20):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac) (for the iMac at least):

> Apple declared the 'i' in iMac to stand for "Internet"; it also represents the product's focus as a personal device ('i' for "individual").

Answer (score 4):

I asked a rep at the Apple store. They said that it stood for Internet, on the first iMac.(As others have answered.) Now it is just a brand.

Answer (score 3):

The whole idea of the first iMac was that you take it out of the box, plug in the power, and then plug in the modem with a phone line.  Internet access made easy. The "i" stood for internet.

Answer (score -2):

It's the I as in me. It means that these things somehow empower you.

Comment: Or hold power over you.

Answer (score -2):

> In technology, the i-word is frequently related to "innovation". So the "i" in iphone could mean "innovative."

Berkun, S. (2010). The Myths of Innovation (First ed., pp. 1-82). Sebastopol, CA: O'Reilly Media, Inc.