# What does the 's' character mean in iPhone 5s and 6s series

Tags: iphone

I found a similar question for iPhone 3Gs and iPhone 4s [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/is-there-an-official-policy-behind-the-s-in-iphone-4s-and-iphone-3gs). So what about the 's' character meaning in 5s and 6s series of iPhone?

Comment: I take it as something like `second thought`, or maybe `superior`.

Comment: I agree with other answers, but I'd like to note something. Whenever Apple appends an S to an iPhone, they change the interior rather than the looks of it. It is true for all generations, for instance the 3G & 3GS look the same, and so do the 4 & 4S, and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The iPhone 5s "**s**" apparently stands for **s**ecurity (they added touch ID), but the "**s**" in iPhone 6s is still largely debated, though some have speculated that it might be for **s**ensitivity (as per the new [3D Touch](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/3d-touch/) features)

However, apple has never really released any official information regarding what the s stands for in any models other than the 3GS and 4s.

But really, I don't think apple plans what the s stands for, it is just a symbol to show that this model has improvements upon its predecessor, but is not altogether different.

Comment: The 4s did have an official *s* in the form of [an interview question answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/27009).

Answer (score 5):

It's debatable.

Some say the "s" always stands for "successor". Like how the 6s makes great improvements on the 6, but since it doesn't have a new design, Apple shouldn't really call it the iPhone 7.

However, Phil Schiller, at the iPhone 3GS release event, said specifically that the S in 3GS stood for "speed", based on how much faster it was than the 3G.

Fans also sometimes make up their own meanings for what the s stands for:

iPhone 4s: Siri

iPhone 5s: Security (for TouchID)

However, at this point, Apple's naming scheme is set after almost a decade and they'll just give every other iPhone name an s, so it likely does just mean **successor**.

Comment: Oops. They haven't used the 'S' moniker since.

Answer (score -5):

s stands for "We don't really have enough features to release a new iPhone, but we're gonna do it anyway."

Comment: IMO s models are much better: Video Recording, Siri, 64-bit processing, TouchID, 3D Touch were all introduced on s models. Non-s models are great and add new features too, but s models really improve on the older model.

Answer (score -5):

the "S" stands for 'Same' IPhone 5Same

Comment: Really? I don't think that the iPhone 5 had TouchID, a 64-bit A7 SoC, came in gold, recorded in slo-mo, or had burst mode.

Comment: I like this joke~