# What started the whole "i" movement?

Tags: mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the “i” in Apple product names mean?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3313/what-does-the-i-in-apple-product-names-mean)

What started the whole "i" movement and what does the "i" stand for when talking about iPods, iPhones, iMacs, iPads and iCarly (woops!).  I think it started with the iMac that came out in the late 90's, but still have always wondered where the "i" came from in terms of the product.  Thanks.

Comment: It stands for 'internet Mac', iMac. There was an answer on this site about it before, but I can't find it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, Apple declared the 'i' in iMac to stand for "Internet"; it also represented the product's focus as a personal device ('i' for "individual").

The following is interesting to see the order, which is effectively iMac, iPod, iLife, iSight, iWork, iPhone, iPad (Where's the iBook?, iTunes?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about [How did Apple choose the 'i' naming convention](http://www.quora.com/History-of-Apple-Inc/How-did-Apple-choose-the-i-naming-convention-iMac-iPod)?

> We returned with five names, one of which we all loved: iMac. Each option came with a presentation board briefly describing why it was a good name. For iMac, it was obviously all about the i. Most important, it stood for Internet. But it also stood for other valuable i things, like individual, imagination, i as in me, etc. It also did a pretty good job of laying a solid foundation for future product naming. The “i” naming nomenclature became so pervasive Steve became the iCEO for a number of years. There was even a Time magazine story that cemented this title.